# DLNA Server work with Sony Bravia

Tags: osx-server

Which DLNA Server do you recommend to install on my mac to make it work with my Sony Bravia?

UPDATE: Mainly interested in support for mkv videos.

Comment: Can you clarify what a DLNA server is, and what is a Sony Bravia?

Comment: DLNA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance Sony Bravia TV: http://www.sony.co.uk/hub/lcd-television

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is plenty fish in that ocean. So it all depends on your patience, budget and admin skills.

If you want good quality for free and easy to setup, I would recommend PS3 media server http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/. It worked well for me.

I sold my Sony gear last year when I moved so I can not attest that it works now but I don't see why it would suddenly break compatibility. It works with all my DLNA clients (with a few limitations over WiFi and perfectly over the wired Gbps network).

There are others and most notably serviio http://www.serviio.org/ that work well but aren't necessarily the simplest to setup.

Have a look at http://alternativeto.net/software/medialink/ to see if you find anything else that you would like.

Comment: thanks for the report. But also support mkv video files?

Comment: It supports many formats... The main page says it all: Real-time video transcoding of MKV/FLV/OGM/AVI, etc

Comment: you mean ps3mediaserver or serviio?

Comment: PS3 Media server does transcoding out of the box, and it also has profiles for many devices so it does the "right" kind of transcoding for your device. Serviio does transcoding too, but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely check in [PS3 Media Server](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/), even if it says PS3 in the name, it uses DLNA to stream out content on the network. It even transcodes all the files using settings of your choice.

I've also been using [Nullriver MediaLink](http://www.nullriver.com/products/medialink), even though it costs you some money, it might be an idea to test it out – it is updated quite often.

Comment: thanks for the report. But also support mkv video files?

Comment: Yepp, both of them supports .mkv, PS3 Media Server even supports embedded subtitles and multiple audio-channels (in different languages, like Eng, Jap, Swe etc.).